# Django template name conflict

Tags: django, templates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Django view - load template from calling app's dir first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092865/django-view-load-template-from-calling-apps-dir-first)

I have Django project with a number of applications. Actually file structure is following:

```
myproj/
  default/
    templates/
      index.html  (1)
  app1/
    templates/
      index.html  (2)
  app2/
    templates/
      index.html  (3)
```

I expected that active application's template directory has highest priority when template resolving. But actually I got the first template accordingly to INSTALLED_APPS order!
If I changing order of installed apps - template is changed correspondingly.

Question: is there way to get template from current application first? Of uniqueness of template name/explicit directory specification is the only way to achieve it?

Comment: You may want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092865/django-view-load-template-from-calling-apps-dir-first

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The usual solution is to put templates in another subdirectory, named after your app, such as:

```
myproj/
  app1/
    templates/
      app1/
        index.html
```

This is done by the shipped applications (such as `django.contrib.admin`) and works pretty well. I usually use generic names like `index.html` in template root for project-specific files (e.g. the index of the whole site).

Comment: That's the Django way. I forgot about that and deleted my answer since this is the right answer in my mind.