# What is the reason for the nested template directory structure in Django?

Tags: python, django

The django template folder [requires](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/part_1.html#add-the-index-view) creating a subfolder with the name of the app which then contains the template files. Why is this necessary, when `python manage.py collectstatic` can infer this information while traversing all directories? It seems very redundant.

Comment: reason is two fold: one is to organize and have a manintainable structure and two to prevent name clashes. suppose you have 2 templates with same name, you could use the dir/template_name in render() to prevent name clashing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, Django does not **require** this specific folder structure for templates to work, it is just a stablished pattern to do so. And, of course, it has a rationale, as pointed in the [official doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial03/#write-views-that-actually-do-something):

> Template namespacing
>
> Now we might be able to get away with putting our templates directly
>   in polls/templates (rather than creating another polls subdirectory),
>   but it would actually be a bad idea. Django will choose the first
>   template it finds whose name matches, and if you had a template with
>   the same name in a different application, Django would be unable to
>   distinguish between them. We need to be able to point Django at the
>   right one, and the easiest way to ensure this is by namespacing them.
>   That is, by putting those templates inside another directory named for
>   the application itself.

You can reference to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11470572/django-template-name-conflict) or [that another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15411164/django-templates-folders) for concrete cases.

In a nutshell, by following this pattern you can have your templates organized in 2 groups:

1. templates related to your specific site or project can live inside the directory pointed by the `TEMPLATES['DIRS']` setting;
2. templates related to a specific app, that could be served *as is* if you make your app pluggable, should live inside `'./appname/templates/appname/'` (and `TEMPLATES['APP_DIRS']` must be True). This way you avoid name conflicts between files inside this folder anf files from outside.

Answer (score 0):

This is a long answer. The idea is to really explain how Django works when loading a template. I even show you some Django source code to explain some points.

Django uses engines to load the templates. This answers works for the default engine `DjangoTemplates` (`django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates`)

---

Let's review your comment:

> "The django template folder requires creating a subfolder with the
> name of the app which then contains the template files."

No, Django doesn't require you to create a subfolder with the name of the app inside the templates folder. IT IS NOT A REQUIREMENT, *it is just a recommendation.*

But why? Let's see it in steps.

### 1) Where does Django look for template files?

> Django searches for template directories in a number of places,
> depending on your template loading settings.

There are two places that are defined in the `settings.py` file. When configuring `TEMPLATES` you have `DIRS` and `APP_DIRS`. Like this:

```
TEMPLATES = [{
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR/"templates"],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        ...
}]
```

- `DIRS`:

> Is a list of directories where Django looks for template source
> files...
>
> This should be set to a list of strings that contain full
> paths to your template directories...
>
> Your templates can go anywhere you want, as long as the directories and templates are readable by the web server...

Example:

```
TEMPLATES = [{
        'DIRS': [
            '/home/html/templates/lawrence.com',
            '/home/html/templates/default',
        ],},]
```

**So you have no required structure from Django**. You can have as many directories you want, where you want, as long as the paths are listed here and readable by the web server. A common case is when you want to have a project folder for your templates that all apps are going to use:

`'DIRS': [BASE_DIR/"templates"]`

This tells Django to find the files in the `templates` folder located in the base directory (the root level).

- `APP_DIRS`:

> Tells whether the engine should look for templates inside installed
> applications...
>
> When `APP_DIRS` is `True`, DjangoTemplates engines look for templates in the templates subdirectory of installed applications...
>
> By convention DjangoTemplates looks for a “templates” subdirectory in
> each of the INSTALLED_APPS...
>
> For each app in INSTALLED_APPS, the loader looks for a templates
> subdirectory. If the directory exists, Django looks for templates in
> there...

It's a boolean value, `True` or `False`.
If `True`, it will look for a `templates` subdirectory inside each app:

```
project/
  appname/
    templates/
```

**This is the only structure that Django requires from you.** If you want to have templates in each app, you must have a `templates` subfolder in the app directory.

If you have this apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = ['myproject.polls', 'myproject.music']
```

And `APP_DIRS: True` Django will look fot templates here.

```
/path/to/myproject/polls/templates/
/path/to/myproject/music/templates/
```

### 2) Why do people recommend having another folder with the app name inside the templates folder (in installed apps)?

It's a matter of orginizing your code and helping Django find the file that you really requested (template namespacing).

Something important to remember: when the template engine loads templates, it checks the template directories in the order they are defined in the `DIRS` setting. If a template with the same name is found in multiple directories, the first one found is used.

After checking the `DIRS` directories, the template engine looks for templates in the `APP_DIRS` directories. If a template with the same name is found in multiple application directories, the one in the first application listed in INSTALLED_APPS is used.

Let's see what could happen if we don't do template namespacing. We have this folders:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = ['project.app_1', 'project.app_2']

project/
  app_1/
    templates/
      detail.html
  app_2/
    templates/
      detail.html
```

If I'm working in the `app_2` view and want to load the template `detail.html` I would have a surprise. Instead of loading the template from `app_2`I would load the template from `app_1`. This is because the files have the same name and `app_1` comes first in `INSTALLED_APPS`.

To avoid this problem we add the app's name inside the template folder.

```
project/
  app_1/
    templates/
      app_1/
        detail.html
  app_2/
    templates/
      app_2/
        detail.html
```

To load the template from the view I would need "app_2/detail.html". I'm being much more specific.

### 3) You can check this in the Django source code.

Go to django/django/template/loaders/app_directories.py and you'll find:

```
class Loader(FilesystemLoader):
    def get_dirs(self):
        return get_app_template_dirs("templates")
```

Which calls `get_app_template_dirs()` and passes "template" as argument.

django/django/template/utils.py

```
@functools.lru_cache
def get_app_template_dirs(dirname):
    """
    Return an iterable of paths of directories to load app templates from.
    dirname is the name of the subdirectory containing templates inside installed applications.
    [NOTE: Remember that "templates" was passed as argument, the dirname]
    """

    template_dirs = [
        Path(app_config.path) / dirname
        for app_config in apps.get_app_configs()
        if app_config.path and (Path(app_config.path) / dirname).is_dir()
    ]
    # Immutable return value because it will be cached and shared by callers.
    return tuple(template_dirs)
```

With `Path(app_config.path)/dirname` you get `appname/templates/`.

For each installed app found here `for app_config in apps.get_app_configs()`.

If the dirs exists `if app_config.path and (Path(app_config.path) / dirname).is_dir()`

`template_dirs` are all the dirs in the installed apps that have a template foler.

### 4) If you're working with Class Based Views (CBV) you can get some functionality done for you.

You have this list view for the `Post` model in the `Blog` app.

```
class BlogListView(ListView):
    model = Post
```

In the absence of an explicit template name, Django will infer one from the object’s (model's) name. In this example:

```
blog/post_list.html
```

The structure is:

appname:   Blog

model:     Post

View type: List

```
appname/<model_name>_<view_type>.html
```

And as you already know, Django looks for a “templates” subdirectory in each of the INSTALLED_APPS.

So, if `APP_DIRS: True`  the full path that the Class Based View would expect to load the templates is:

```
/path/to/project/blog/templates/blog/post_list.html
```

This is a predefined requirement of the CBV, but it can be modified if
you define a `template_name` argument.

```
class BlogListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "blog/the_super_list_of_posts.html"
```

You can check this in the source code:

Go to django/django/views/generic/list.py

```
class MultipleObjectTemplateResponseMixin(TemplateResponseMixin):
    """Mixin for responding with a template and list of objects."""

     template_name_suffix = "_list"
     
    def get_template_names(self):
    """
    Return a list of template names to be used for the request. Must return
    a list. May not be called if render_to_response is overridden.
    """
        try:
            names = super().get_template_names()
        except ImproperlyConfigured:
            # If template_name isn't specified, it's not a problem --
            # we just start with an empty list.
            names = []

    # If the list is a queryset, we'll invent a template name based on the
    # app and model name. This name gets put at the end of the template
    # name list so that user-supplied names override the automatically-
    # generated ones.
        if hasattr(self.object_list, "model"):
            opts = self.object_list.model._meta
            names.append(
                "%s/%s%s.html"
                % (opts.app_label, opts.model_name, 
self.template_name_suffix)
        )
        elif not names:
            raise ImproperlyConfigured(
                "%(cls)s requires either a 'template_name' attribute "
                "or a get_queryset() method that returns a QuerySet."
               % {
                    "cls": self.__class__.__name__,
                 }
        )
        return names
```

You have:

```
names = super().get_template_names() # get's the appname/templates
...
names.append(
    "%s/%s%s.html"
    % (opts.app_label, opts.model_name, self.template_name_suffix)
)
```

Where:

opts.app_label: is the app's name

opts.model_name: is the model's name

self.template_name_suffix: is the suffix, in this case "_list"

All together they make the default's template name that the CBV looks for:

```
app_label/templates/app_label/<model_name>_<template_name_suffix>.html
```

**DOCUMENTATION.**

1. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/api/
2. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/templates/
3. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/intro/tutorial03/#write-views-that-actually-do-something
4. https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/template/loaders/app_directories.py
5. https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/template/utils.py
6. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/