# django - urls.py root path set

Tags: python, django, django-urls

When I enter `localhost:8000` or `localhost:8000/store`, both views are same as `home/index.html`.
I want these paths to set different view.

#### urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'', 'home.views.index', name='view_home'),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^store/$', 'store.views.store_list', name='view_store_list'),
    url(r'^store/(?P<store_id>\d+)$', 'store.views.single_store')
]
```

#### views.py - home

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    return render(
        request,
        'index.html'
    )
```

#### views.py - store

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse

from .models import Store # fetch Store model

from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger # paginate
def store_list(request):
    store_list = Store.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(store_list, 2)

    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        stores = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        stores = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        stores = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    return render(
        request,
        'index.html',
        {
            'stores': stores,
        }
    )
```

cheers!

#### edit:

I also tried `url(r'^$', 'home.views.index', name='view_home'),`, however it brings same result.

Comment: Can you post the relevant views code?

Comment: Why do you use same template `index.html` for two different views?

Comment: Is it not different? These templates have different path each other.
`home/templates/index.html` and `store/templates/index.html`

Comment: "These templates have different path each other. home/templates/index.html and store/templates/index.html" is home and store are name of your apps?

Comment: @mhassan yes! These are name of apps in my same project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think as your template name is conflicting with each other. You can make one templates folder for you whole project like this

```
Project
   |>Templates
   |>store
   |>home
```

In templates, you can put your templates like this

```
 Project
   |>Templates
        store
            |>index.html
        home
            |>index.html
   |store
   |home
```

Now you can give path of your template like this

```
def index(request):
return render(
    request,
    'home/index.html'
)
```

If you want to keep templates in directory under you app, then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092865/django-view-load-template-from-calling-apps-dir-first) issue might help you.

Answer (score 4):

You need to anchor and terminate the pattern for the root view:

```
 url(r'^$', 'home.views.index', name='view_home'),
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a trailing slash '/' in

```
url(r'^store/$', 'store.views.store_list', name='view_store_list')
```

so it will be valid for the url `localhost:8000/store/` but not for the url `localhost:8000/store`. So you need to remove trailing slash.

Plus @Daniel is right you need the put the home URL like he mentioned in his answer. Trailing slash is the reason you could not get it to work after changing the home URL.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem, as mentioned by Daniel is the url pattern, if you just set the empty string it will always match. Therefore you should use  `url(r'^$', 'home.views.index', name='view_home')`. With `r'^$'` you are saying that the pattern match only with the empty string. Alternatively you can move this url at the end of the list and it will be used as the default view if anything else matches.

The second problem I see is that in your `store_list` view you are returning:

```
return render(
    request,
    'index.html',
    {
        'stores': stores,
    }
)
```

Are you using the same template, `index.html`, for both index and store or is it just a copy and paste error? If so, are you sure that the `stores` variable contains data? If you don't have any result the outcome will be the same as the index view.