# How to get the template path in the view django

Tags: django, django-views

So I'm trying to get the template path in my view. Is there a dynamic way of doing this because at the moment I am hard-coding the path.

```
html = 'C:/Users/user/Desktop/project/src/templates/project.html'
```

**Templates Path**

```
TEMPLATES = [
   'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")],
]
```

**View**

```
html = 'C:/Users/user/Desktop/project/src/templates/project.html'
open_html = open(html, 'r')
soup =  BeautifulSoup(open_html, "html5lib")
image = soup.find('img', {'name':'image_url'})
img_url = image.get('src')
open_html.close()
```

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092865/django-view-load-template-from-calling-apps-dir-first

Comment: The beauty of Django is that it will autodiscover your template files based on the folder structure - `app/templates/app/project.html`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. get template location from your project setting file.

```
from your_project_name.settings import BASE_DIR

path = os.path.join(BASE_DIR+'templates/', 'project.html')
open_html = open(path, 'r')
soup =  BeautifulSoup(open_html, "html5lib")
image = soup.find('img', {'name':'image_url'})
img_url = image.get('src')
open_html.close()
```

Answer (score 4):

If you load the template....

```
mytemplate = loader.get_template('myapp/templatename.html')
```

What you get in return is a Template object.

One of the members of this object is the origin attribute, which itself has an attribute called 'name'

```
templatepath = mytemplate.origin.name
```

This is the full path to the template file that the template loader discovered.

Comment: `from django.template import loader` is where loader comes from

Comment: Another comment, is this is quite slow because it parses the template too, not just find it.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to store your templates within your app.
for example, if your app called polls your template should be at polls/templates/polls/

You can read more about it here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial03/