# Django: Get absolute file path of template file from template name, without parsing the template

Tags: django

How to get the absolute file path of a template file from it's template name, without parsing the template?

E.g. given `foo/bar.html` return `home/user/project/app/foo/templates/foo/bar.html`

The `django.template.loader.get_template` will parse the template.

I think there was a `django.template.loader.find_template` but it was deprecated.

Please note this is not a duplicate of [How to get the template path in the view django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44896014/how-to-get-the-template-path-in-the-view-django) because that solution parses the whole template, which is slow when trying to find the path of many `template_name`s.

Please note the templates files are spread across various apps in various places, so it needs to use the template loader engine to find them. hard coding some dir with suffixes won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Reverse engineered this from the python source code:

```py
import os
from django import template

def find_template(template_name: str) -> str:
    for engine in template.engines.all():
        for loader in engine.engine.template_loaders:
            for origin in loader.get_template_sources(template_name):
                if os.path.exists(origin.name):
                    return origin.name
    raise template.TemplateDoesNotExist(f"Could not find template: {template_name}")
```